# react native packages install for Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

I've been using React Native for a little while now and I've always struggled with some of the gradle stuff for the Android side of things. Since 0.60.0 the iOS side has been great with using the pod file.

I have started to use a package for SQLite (https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) and the instructions have details for `react-native.config.js` file (RN > 0.60.0). Can this file be used for to replace all of the usual gradle settings with the other packages in my projects. It would be great to have all this stuff in one place instead of some in the `react-native.config.js` file and some in `gradle.build`

Thanks in advance for any help